# How to simplify this code, which uses Option.fold in Scala?

Tags: scala, fold, scala-option

Suppose I have the following functions

```
def foo(x: Int): Option[String] = ...
def bar(s: String): Option[String] = ...
```

and

```
def f(s: String): String = ...
def g(s: String): String = ...
```

I would like to compose all these functions as follows:

```
def qux(x: Int): String = {
   val s1 = foo(x).fold("defaultFoo") { str => f(str) }
   bar(s1).fold("defaultBar") { str => g(str) }
}
```

In my opinion function `qux` does not look particularly elegant and I wonder how to simplify it. How would you suggest write `qux` ?

Comment: Is the `str = g(str)` supposed to be `str => g(str)`?

Comment: @DonRoby Yes, I am fixing the code.

Comment: `x.fold(default)(x => f(x)) == x.fold(default)(f)` makes it nicer

Answer (score 2):

With simple usage of `map`:

```
def quz(x: Int) = 
  bar(foo(x).fold("defaultFoo")(f))
    .map(g).getOrElse("defaultBar")
```

Comment: Where is "defaultFoo" here ?

Comment: @Michael ops, yes, then not that beautiful

Comment: I'd recommend going either `fold` or `map`/`getOrElse`. It seems like mostly a matter of taste in choosing between them. But why use both?

Answer (score 1):

To codify what other's have said, the first major improvement would be to let [eta-expansion](http://gleichmann.wordpress.com/2011/01/09/functional-scala-turning-methods-into-functions/) work for you instead of manually making closures:

```
def qux(x: Int): String = {
  val s1 = foo(x).fold("defaultFoo")(f)
  bar(s1).fold("defaultBar")(g)
}
```

You could also use a `for...yield` comprehension to defer your default case until the end:

```
def qux(x: Int): String = {
   val result = for { s1 <- foo(x); s2 <- bar(f(s1)) } yield { g(s2) } 
   result.getOrElse("default result")
}
```

The issue here is that you lose the error handling you have in the middle of your control flow, because the simpler combinators pass through `None` cases. If you need to preserve that same flow, you might try this:

```
def qux(x: Int): String = {
   val s1 = foo(x).map(f).getOrElse("defaultFoo") 
   bar(s1).map(g).getOrElse("defaultBar")
}
```

It's not hugely simpler than your original code, but it's a little terser, and pushes error handling to the end of each line. Or just leave out the intermediate variable, and make it a one-liner:

```
def qux(x: Int): String = bar(foo(x).map(f).getOrElse("defaultFoo")).map(g).getOrElse("defaultBar")
```